# what does ARRAY_CONSTRAIN and ARRAYFORMULA do?

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula below in excel that works perfectly and never had any problems with;

```
=IF(A2="";"";INDEX('PLACEMENT List'!$A:$AA;'INVOICE List'!$A2;MATCH('INVOICE List'!$C$1;'PLACEMENT List'!$A$2:$AA$2;0)))
```

In googlesheets I uploaded the same file with everything still working the way it should but the formula is different

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2="","",INDEX('PLACEMENT List'!$A:$AA,'INVOICE List'!$A2,MATCH('INVOICE List'!$C$1,'PLACEMENT List'!$A$2:$AA$2,0)))), 1, 1)
```

I can remove ARRAY_CONSTRAIN and ARRAYFORMULA and the result is still the same, running very smooth but it makes me wonder what these extra formulas do, are they important? It was a file I uploaded 2 years ago so I cant remember if I added them or googlesheets added them in the upload. Basically trying to decide if I should keep them there or not?

Comment: No, you do not need them.

Comment: Thanks! was worried about taking them out